# How can create new score profiling into Sitecore?

Tags: sitecore-api, azure-search

I am indexing Sitecore items into `Azure` and performing the `Azure search via Azure functions`.

I want to create a new Scoring Profile into Sitecore and use it during the search.
I am not getting much help from google on this topic. I tried doing it in many ways however didn't get the proper solution. Therefore, It will be helpful if anyone can share any references like a blog, post, etc. which can guide me to achieve scoring based on full-text search.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify: do you mean behavioural profiles?  (the ones created in the Marketing Control Panel)? Do you want to apply scores during search or do you want to filter results based on previously applied scores?

Comment: I want to apply scores during the search based on the text user enters for the search. My requirement is, I want to fetch documents matched in the title field more relevant than documents that matched in the description field. Hope this clarifies..

Comment: is it not something you can get by Boosting through the code? I am not sure but the azure scoring profile will work on the item level only.

Comment: @Mahendra Shekhawat - And that's the challenge I am facing here. How to boost multiple items based on the search text. I have 3 fields 1) Title 2) Summary 3) Description and I want to sort the results by the priority of search terms/ phrase matches by Title, Summary and Description.

Comment: I got this work at azure end. But i am unable to add new scoring profile in the Sitecore config. Currently when i do the index rebuild from Sitecore, it wipes out all the scoring profile created on the azure end.So now the challenge is, how can define new scoring profile with title & description fields weight at Sitecore config?

Comment: can you share some code and configurations, how you are doing all this? usually, you can create multiple scoring profile but can only add one in an "active" scoring profile at a time.

Comment: File Name - 'Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.DefaultIndexConfiguration.Config'             '<scoringProfile functionType="" interpolationType="" boostingRangeStart="1" boostingRangeEnd="10" cloudFieldName="metadatatitle_S" scoringProfileName="globalsearch" scoringProfileBoostValue="10" constantBoostBeyondRange="false" />'

Comment: I have followed below link https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/92/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/sitecore-azure-search-item-level-boosting.html